# Como verificar as portas tty conectadas em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho um dispositivo que é conectado ao computador e preciso verificar quais dispositivos estão conectados e informações sobre o dispositivo, para então pegar o nome da porta e iniciar uma comunicação. Como posso fazer isso em Python? Ou pelo menos verificar quais portas estão conectadas?